# Schema.org is not validating: "it appears to include multiple reviews of an item, but no aggregate review information"

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

I am trying to implement Schema.org structured data to my website. On one of my pages, I have a possibility for users to rate and review a tourist attraction (for example St. Stephan's Cathedral in Vienna). Now I want to enhance my HTML with structured data for it.

Here is an example code of it (also available on http://pastebin.com/u8YZtrpW):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
<head></head>
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">


<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
    <article class="boxy-full">
        <div>
            <div class="rating" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating" title="Rating: 4.50/5 <br># Ratings: 10">
                <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.50"/>
                <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5"/>
                <meta itemprop="ratingCount" content="10"/>

                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></i>
            </div>
        </div>

        <h1 itemprop="name">Vienna - St. Stephan's Cathedral</h1>

        <div class="ccheader">
            <meta itemprop="image" content="/myimg.jpg"/>
            <img src="/myimg.jpg" alt="St. Stephan's Cathedral"/>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <p>Here comes some text to describe the Place...</p>
        </div>
    </article>

    <div class="boxy-full">
        <h2>User-Bewertungen</h2>

        <article class="blueblock" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
            <div class="pull-right" itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
                <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="5"/>
                <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5"/>
                <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1">
                <div class="rating" title="Rating: 5/5" data-placement="bottom">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <meta itemprop="itemreviewed" content="Stephansdom in Wien">
            <h3 itemprop="name">Review 1 Title</h3>

            <div class="co" itemprop="reviewBody">
                Here comes some review text...
            </div>
            <footer class="small">Created by Gastuser, on 19.01.2015
                <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2015-01-19">
            </footer>
        </article>

        <article class="blueblock" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
            <div class="pull-right" itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
                <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="5"/>
                <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5"/>
                <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1">
                <div class="rating" title="Rating: 5/5" data-placement="bottom">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <meta itemprop="itemreviewed" content="Stephansdom in Wien">
            <h3 itemprop="name">Review 1 Title</h3>

            <div class="co" itemprop="reviewBody">
                Here comes some review text...
            </div>
            <footer class="small">Created by Gastuser, on 19.01.2015
                <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2015-01-19">
            </footer>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My problem now is, that the Google webmaster tool for testing structured data (https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) gives me the following error message:

> No rich snippet will be generated for this data, because it appears to include multiple reviews of an item, but no aggregate review information.

But there is an aggregated rating markup. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Its ok, that my question gets downvoted, but it would be nice to comment WHY it gets downvoted, so I can improve the question. I have read the schema.org documentation, used the google testtool, posted urls to the code, etc. Whats wrong with the question?

Comment: Not sure if it’s the reason for the downvotes, but you should include a [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of the code that gives this error in your question. Otherwise this question is of no use to others if your page’s code changes (or if the page goes 404).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have added a complete, but cleaned up code example and a pastebin link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know why Google’s [old SDTT](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) reports this, but their [new SDTT](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/structured-data/testing-tool/) doesn’t:

Apart from the [`author` property](http://schema.org/author) that Google would like to see for the [`Review`](http://schema.org/Review) items, no relevant errors or warnings are reported.

Comment: Huch, you are right! I added the author property and now, everything validates fine on the new SDTT, but the old SDTT reports the same error. Really weird. Another point is, that google can't understand the schema.org breadcrumb (see https://developers.google.com/webmasters/structured-data/breadcrumbs?hl=de#examples) so I had to switch to the old data-vocabulary :(